# Ubuntu logs me out if I touch the screen

Tags: session, logout, touchscreen

I just fixed it so it worked after suspension, and tried to enable multitouch.

Now if I touch the screen at all, I'm sent back to the display manager and have to log in again.

I've uninstalled EVERY package I installed today, and it's still doing it. I have no idea why, or how to figure out why.

Edit: Earlier I found the logs...

Turned on a seconds counter, and touched the screen at exactly 15:06:00.##

```
May 27 15:06:01 Luna gnome-session[3029]: Gdk-WARNING: gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.#012
May 27 15:06:02 Luna acpid: client 3005[0:0] has disconnected
May 27 15:06:02 Luna acpid: client connected from 3385[0:0]
May 27 15:06:02 Luna acpid: 1 client rule loaded
May 27 15:06:06 Luna lxdm-binary: pam_ecryptfs: Passphrase file wrapped
May 27 15:06:12 Luna gnome-session[3410]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'gnome-shell'
May 27 15:06:14 Luna rtkit-daemon[1835]: Successfully made thread 3504 of process 3504 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
May 27 15:06:14 Luna rtkit-daemon[1835]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
May 27 15:06:14 Luna pulseaudio[3504]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
May 27 15:06:14 Luna rtkit-daemon[1835]: Successfully made thread 3520 of process 3504 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
May 27 15:06:14 Luna rtkit-daemon[1835]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
May 27 15:06:14 Luna rtkit-daemon[1835]: Successfully made thread 3521 of process 3504 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
May 27 15:06:14 Luna rtkit-daemon[1835]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
May 27 15:06:15 Luna goa[3546]: goa-daemon version 3.4.0 starting [main.c:112, main()]
```

Comment: Sounds like it's crashing X, which would return to the login screen once X restarts.

Comment: Okay, so (I found the logs at around 3) but I don't know how to determine why it's crashing.

Comment: Looks like hardware-dependent, can you add more details about your configuration?

Comment: Although OP last signed on ~1 year ago he never responded to request for more information posted 5+ years ago. The question is about EOL Ubuntu version so VTC as `not reproducible`.